# how to prevent autofix value in xdsoft datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

i am using [xdoft calender plugin](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) I want to stop autofix of calendar, when user edit value with some weird characters like `01.01.20asdasd18` or `11111.01.2018` it converts value to min date `31.12.1899` and I dont want it

how to prevent it to fix value?

here is def;

```
$('#cetvelBaslangic').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
    autoclose: true

});
```

Comment: which plugin whats the link ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam hello, edited post